# Mixing memory - different brands, same specs - will it work?

Tags: memory, ddr3

I'm needing to upgrade a system with a single 8G Kingston PC3L-12800E-11-13-E3 module.   Unfortunately I seem unable to get another identical module.    If I can find memory from another supplier which has identical specs, will it work reliably as dual channel memory?

Assuming identical memory can I be sure will work reliably in an Intel CPU based system - are there any other variables I can "ignore" - Can I, for example, use any PC3L-12800E memory ?  What about PC3L-14900E or PCL3-10600E memory?

(If it makes any difference, my specific system is an Acer Altos T310 F3 system)

Comment: *"memory ... which has identical specs"* -- Not really identical unless they are intentionally matched.  The *"specs"* do not specify a tolerance, so you have no idea how precise the timing and voltage specs really are.  Nor do you know *a prioi* how much variation dual channel can tolerate.  Even if they don't work in dual-channel mode, they should work in single-channel mode.

Comment: @sawdust - yes, I should have said idntical specs